# How can I sum up the exponent value in bash shell?

Tags: perl, bash

here are the example values

```
2.31312e+06
4.34234234e+07
4.578362e+06
3.213124124e+06
```

how can I add them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers are args:

```
perl -le'$s += $_ for @ARGV; END { print $s }'
```

Numbers on STDIN or file named as argument (one per line):

```
perl -nle'$s += $_; END { print $s }'
```

Use `printf '%e\n', $s` instead of `print $s` if you want the result in exponent notation.

Comment: thanks ikegami your answer is what i need, actually the value I was stored in array 
e.g. arr[0]=2.31312e+06 ,arr[1]=4.34234234e+07 ,arr[2]=4.578362e+06 and arr[3]=3.213124124e+06

how can i do??

Comment: `perl -le'$s += $_ for @ARGV; END { print $s }' "${arr[@]}"`

Comment: It work perfectly and exactly what I want! thanks for you reply and
I just learn shell script for several day. Sorry that give you so much troubles

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk`.  The following assumes that every number in the file is on a separate line:

```
awk '{a+=$0}END{print a}' filename
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
5.3528e+07
```

If all the numbers in the file are on the same line, say:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) a+=$i}END{print a}' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Perl version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $sum = 0;

while (<DATA>) {
    $sum += $_;
}

print "$sum\n";

__DATA__
2313120
43423423.4
4578362
3213124.124
```

---

Here is the one-liner version, if you prefer this style:

```
perl -ne ' $s += $_; END { print "$s\n" } ' datafile
```